# Dataset from database is empty

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2013, dataset

I'm accessing a table from my database. I have added the tables as a dataset in Visual Studio 2013, but when I try to use it, it comes out empty.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
IQueryable<NorthwindDataSet.OrdersRow> LookupOrdersForYear(int year)
{
    using (var context = new NorthwindDataSet())
    {
        var orders =
            from order in context.Orders
            where order.OrderDate != null && order.OrderDate.Year >= year
            select order;
        return orders.ToList().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

I found out that `orders` was empty, so I added

```
Console.WriteLine(context.Orders.Count);
```

which gave me an output of 0. What went wrong?

Comment: What DataSet? What is the value of `year`? Do you get anything if you completely remove the `where` clause?

Comment: @Crowcoder I don't get anything, even if I remove the `where` clause. The dataset comes from the Northwind database, which I added to my Visual Studio project by selecting **Add data source**. This piece of code is part of a method, where year is the input (type of int).

Comment: your DataSet and your DbContext are separate things. We don't have enough information to help which is why , I assume, the downvote.

Comment: @Crowcoder I added the Northwind datasource using Visual Studio, and it automatically added a NorthwindDataSet to my project. I'm sure this is a dataset. What other information should I add to clarify?

Comment: apologies, I read it wrong. You need to Fill the Dataset with data, use a SqlDataAdapter. It is not populated with data just by adding it to the Form.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you, your suggestion worked. Would you like to post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74488/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-mmking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I needed to fill my dataset with data, or it would stay empty.

A SqlDataAdapter did the trick:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Orders");
string connString = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

adapter.SelectCommand = command;
adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = conn;
adapter.Fill(context.Orders);
```

---

There are several overloaded methods for SqlDataAdapter.Fill, of which one takes a dataset and another takes a datatable. When I first used the SqlDataAdapter, I used the one that takes a dataset

```
adapter.Fill(context);
```

which still gave me an empty context.Orders. The correct one takes a datatable:

```
adapter.Fill(context.Orders);
```

This one worked and returned the dates as expected.